# Understanding the induced morphism of Tor and splitting of universal coefficient theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

My question is partially motivated by [The succession of the coefficient theorem is split but not naturally](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329296/the-succession-of-the-coefficient-theorem-is-split-but-not-naturally).

**Definition**. Let $A \in \mathsf{Ab}$ and $B \in \mathsf{Ab}$. Then, for a free resolution $$F_{\bullet}: \  ... \to F_1 \to F_0 \to A \to 0$$ one obtains the complex $$F_{\bullet} \otimes B: \ ... \to F_1 \otimes B \to F_0 \otimes B \to A \otimes B \to 0$$ which allows to apply the $n$-th homology functor as a measure for exactness for all $n \in \mathbf{Z}$. One then defines $$\mathrm{Tor}_n^{\mathbf{Z}}(A,B):=H_n(F_{\bullet}\otimes B).$$

This leads to a covariant functor $$\mathrm{Tor}_n^{\mathbf{Z}}(-,B): \mathsf{Ab} \to \mathsf{Ab}.$$ I now wonder, what is the induced morphism $\mathrm{Tor}(f)$ for $f:A \to C, f \ \mathbf{Z}$-linear? I know that $\mathrm{Tor}$ is invariant (up to isomorphism) under change of free resolution and that $f$ induces a chain map $\bar{f}_{\bullet}:F_{\bullet}^A \to F^B_{\bullet}$, satisfying $\bar{f}_{-1}=f.$ Do I just pick an arbitrary chain map that extends $f$ and then compute $H_{\bullet}(\bar{f} \otimes B)$ which gives me, independent of the choice of $\bar{f}$ (since two such are chain homotopic), a morphism between $\mathrm{Tor}_n^{\mathbf{Z}}(A,B) \to \mathrm{Tor}_n^{\mathbf{Z}}(C,B)$, or in this case between $\mathrm{Tor}_1^{\mathbf{Z}}(A,B) \to \mathrm{Tor}_1^{\mathbf{Z}}(C,B)$, since all other $\mathrm{Tor}$-groups vanish. In a more general setting of $R$-modules one would then have those for all $n$, I supppose? This seems really hard to compute in general, is that true?

Regarding the linked post: If I understand it correctly, one picks the chain complexes $C_{\bullet}$ with $C_0=\mathbf{Z}=C_1$ and $C_n=0$ otherwise, with $d_1= 2 \cdot,d_n=0, n \neq 1$ as well as $C'_{\bullet}$ with $C'_1=\mathbf{Z}=C'_0, C'_n=0$ otherwise with $d'_n=0$ for all $n \in \mathbf{Z}$. Let $f_{\bullet}:C_{\bullet} \to C'_{\bullet}, f_1=\mathrm{id},f_n=0, n\neq 1.$ Thus $H_n(f)=0$ for all $n \in \mathbf{Z},$ since ​$$\mathrm{ker}(d'_{n})/\mathrm{im}(d'_{n+1})=0$$ for all $n \in \mathbf{Z}$. Tensoring with $G:=\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ gives $$H_n(f \otimes \mathrm{id}): H_n(C_{\bullet} \otimes G) \to H_n(C'_{\bullet} \otimes G)$$ with $H_1(f \otimes \mathrm{id})$ being the identity. What happens to $\mathrm{Tor}$? I would want to show that $$0 = \mathrm{Tor}(f): \mathrm{Tor}_1^{\mathbf{Z}}(H_0(C_{\bullet}),G) \to \mathrm{Tor}_1^{\mathbf{Z}}(H_0(C'_{\bullet}),G),$$ which I can conclude since $H_0(C'_{\bullet},G)=0$, so I do not need to actually compute $\mathrm{Tor}(f)$ like in my first question. This essentially works because $H_0(C'_{\bullet})=\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ and thus $\mathrm{Tor}_1^{\mathbf{Z}}(H_0(C_{\bullet}),G) \simeq \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ (and thus non-zero), right?

**Edit:** Does there exist an easy counterexample for topological spaces too?

Comment: I think you need to take the *pullback* squares to obtain the chain morphism.

Comment: @Berci I am sorry, but I am not familiar with what you commented. Could you please explain what you mean? Thank you in advance!